# Error in installing a software named chatterbot

Tags: python

I am getting the following error when I try to install ChatterBot 0.6.0

Error is:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chatterBot (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for chatterBot

The command I used for running is:

```
pip install chatterBot
```

I am running it in Windows 8 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

The package does not work for your python version. If you are using 3.6, lower it to 3.5; if you are on python 2, 2.7 should be fine.

Comment: Once you tried, please let me know whether that works. Cheers!